# Python: How to Extract Zip-Files in Google Cloud Storage Without Running Out of Memory?

Tags: python, memory, zip, google-cloud-storage, dask

I need to extract the files in a zip file in Google Cloud Storage. I'm using a python function to do this, but I keep running into memory issues even when using a Dask Cluster and each Dask worker has a 20GB memory limit.

How could I optimize my code so that it doesn't consume as much memory? Perhaps reading the zip file in chunks and streaming them to a temporary file and then sending this file to Google Cloud Storage?

Would appreciate any guidance here.

Here is my code:

```
@task
def unzip_files(
    bucket_name,
    zip_data
):
    file_date = zip_data['file_date']
    gcs_folder_path = zip_data['gcs_folder_path']
    gcs_blob_name = zip_data['gcs_blob_name']

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    destination_blob_pathname = f'{gcs_folder_path}/{gcs_blob_name}'
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_pathname)
    zipbytes = io.BytesIO(blob.download_as_string())

    if is_zipfile(zipbytes):
        with ZipFile(zipbytes, 'r') as zipObj:
            extracted_file_paths = []
            for content_file_name in zipObj.namelist():
                content_file = zipObj.read(content_file_name)
                extracted_file_path = f'{gcs_folder_path}/hgdata_{file_date}_{content_file_name}'
                blob = bucket.blob(extracted_file_path)
                blob.upload_from_string(content_file)
                extracted_file_paths.append(f'gs://{bucket_name}/{extracted_file_path}')
        return extracted_file_paths

    else:
        return []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not quite follow your code, but in general, dask plays nicely with complex file operations like this, using the `fsspec` and `gcsfs` libraries. For example (and you don't need Dask for this)

```
import fsspec

with fsspec.open_files("zip://*::gcs://gcs_folder_path/gcs_blob_name") as open_files:
    for of in open_files:
        with fsspec.open("gcs://{something from fo}", "wb") as f:
            data = True
            while data:
                data = of.read(2**22)
                f.write(data)
```

You could instead do

```
open_files = fssec.open_files(...)
```

and parallelise the loop with Dask.

Comment: Fascinating! I will give this a shot. Thanks so much!